# SAS repeating a set of statements for each value of macro

Tags: sas

I have say two tables in teradata one of them-Reports is like this

```
Year    Report_ID   BAD_PART_NUMBERS
2015    P12568  6989820
2015    P12568  1769819
2015    P12568  1988700
2015    P12697  879010
2015    P12697  287932
2015    P12697  17902
```

and the other table-Orders

```
order_no    Customer_id Purchase dt PART_NUM    PART_DESC
265187  B1792   3/4/2016    02-6989820  gfsahj
1669    B1792   7/8/2017    01-32769237 susisd
1692191 B1794   5/7/2015    03-6989820  gfsahj
16891   B1794   3/24/2016   78-1769819  ysatua
62919   B1794   2/7/2017    15-3287629  at8a9s7d
```

One of my objective is to find the part number that was most frequently purchased after purchasing a bad part, for every Report_ID
For one report_ID I wrote the code like this:

```
 %let REPORT_ID=('P12568');
 Proc SQL;
 connect to teradata as tera1 (server='XXX' user=&userid pwd=&pwd Database 
 ="XXXXX" );
create table BAD_PART as
select * from connection to tera1
(
 select REPORT_ID,BAD_PART_NUMBERS from REPORTS where REPORT_ID=&REPORT_ID 
 *other where conditions
 group by 1,2
 )
;
disconnect from tera1;
quit;
/*creating a PART_NUM macro*/
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
SELECT quote(cats('%',BAD_PART_NUMBERS),"'")  
INTO :PART_NUM separated by ", "
FROM BAD_PART ;
QUIT;

%put macro variable PART_NUM:&PART_NUM;

/*FINDING SECONDARY PART INFORMATION*/
proc sql;
 connect to teradata as tera1 (server='XXXX' user=&userid pwd=&pwd Database 
 =" XXXX" );
create table SEC_PART as
select * from connection to tera1
(
SELECT  &REPORT_ID as REPORT_ID, PART_NUM, PART_DESC,COUNT (DISTINCT ORDER) 
as frequency
       from (
select  Customer_id,Min(Purchase_dt)  as FIRST_BAD_PART_PURCHASE
from    ORDERS  
where       (PART_NUM like any(&PART_NUM)) A
left join (
select  Customer_id, Purchase_dt, PART_NUM, PART_DESC,ORDER
from    ORDERS group by 1,2,3,4,5 ) B 
                        on A. Customer_id =B. Customer_id
    AND FIRST_BAD_PART_PURCHASE< Purchase_dt 
group by 1,2,3 order by frequency desc
having frequency>0
)
;
disconnect from tera1;
quit;

/*---various PROC SQL and Data steps*/
```

Ultimately, I have a dataset which has

```
 Report_ID  MONTHS  VALUE
 P12568     0       21
 P12568     1       34
 P12568     2       40.38
 P12568     3       67.05
 P12568     4       100.08
```

where months here is continous which is MONTHS of exposure. For every report_id the final table needs to be appended.Suppose I am interested in seeing for all report_id for a year eg;

```
select REPORT_ID from reports where year='2015'.
```

Right now my code is doing for one Report_ID but if I am interested to find for more than one at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try performing the entire query in Teradata.  Instead constructing the any list, join to the bad_part query and use concatenation to construct the like pattern.

Deep in the query try having a

```
JOIN ( select part_num bad_part_num from <bad part_num query> ) bad_list ON 
PART_NUM like '%' || bad_list.bad_part_num
```

instead of the

```
where       (PART_NUM like any(&PART_NUM)) A
```

wherein the any list is, a list of % prefaced bad part numbers, constructed via SAS Proc SQL (into :) macro.

Comment: I am not sure How I add the join in the present query(SEC_PART) where I am trying to find all the related customer id that had purchased the badpart first time and to find after which those customer_id  getting other parts

Comment: Are the ***other where conditions** in the BAD_PART determination always the same, regardless of REPORT_ID ?

Comment: Your example shows BAD_PART table as a result of SELECT REPORT_ID,REPORT_DESC. How does the PART_NUM get into the table BAD_PART (when you use cats('%',PART_NUM)  ?

Comment: Yes the other where conditions are same for any Report_ID. I corrected the column names in the code

Comment: Regarding **most frequently purchased after purchasing a bad part**. If ORDERS has a customer that purchases a bad part more than once do the 'frequencies' reset when the bad part is purchase ?  Suppose X and Z are bad, and A, B, C, D are ok, and the part date order purchases are  A B C X A D Z C A B C -- are the *part:freq* results A:1 D:1 B:1 C:2 or A:2 D:1 B:1 C:2. A:2 would arise from <bad> A <bad> A

Comment: If this is one customer then, I would like the counts to be A:2   D:1  B:1 C:2, BTW I would not consider the bad parts in the list as well which is nice that you got it and I would eliminate it. What I am thinking is can I either get the list of parts by frequency for all report_id in one table if possible or use one value of Report_id at a time and repeat the set of steps for each report_id and append each of these and get the combined list for all report_ids

Comment: In order to have a useful single query, the various counting conditions have to be considered.  The conditions affect how data grouping will be, especially aggregate functions and their `partition`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176344/discussion-between-viji-and-richard).